# How to use color string references in ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, android-layout

I find myself duplicating colors all over my Styles.css. When I would like to change that color, i would have to change it for about 10 times (and more as i go). 
In Android you can write colors in an xml file and refer to them when you need a color. 
Is there a way to do this in ASP.NET or css?
I am sorry if there already is a solution somewhere on the internet, I am sure someone solved this, I just can not find it.

Comment: i would recommend looking into Less or Sass, they are both CSS pre processors that let you assign colors into variable names, as well as many other functions.

Comment: Sass seems like a good solution to me. How do I know if the server the asp.net project will be running on supports Sass? If I follow these http://sass-lang.com/install steps, is that enough to make it run on my localhost and on the server it will be running on later? I mean, will it be installed in my project or on this computer?

Comment: unfortunately, I have not used it enough to answer those questions :( but I do hope I got you on the right path!